# PHP Laravel route not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-routing

I've installd PHP laravel from Composer so i created a route:

```
Route::get('cats/{id}', function()
{
return "Cat #$id";
});
```

But when i get into: http://www.oktech-servers.net/cats/12345

A error msg prompt: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

I want to mention also the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My host administrator says that mod-rewrite is working properly but i can't find why i get this error!!

Regards.

Comment: oops some thing wrong there is an error in your code? turn on the error in the laravel. Than you wil know what wrong in there

Comment: The error after set debug to true is: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined variable: id!!

Comment: Thats mean you did not defined your variable. In route {}

Comment: as you not returning any file you neeed to define the variable before using it. hope it help

Comment: I am newbie in this, how i define the var?...

Comment: can you just add. in route { before return $id=12345;} Than tell me what happened. And rest of the code will remain same. Thanks

Comment: Already defined... thank you :) works great!!

Comment: and if it worked. can i post the answer here and gonna accept the solution. ?? given if it worked

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

From the [**Laravel documentation**](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) on routes:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Notice the `function($id)`, this is where the variable gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line 
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

to

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

on httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

get thet parameter $id in your function. You have not used it

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id) {
   return 'User '.$id;
});
```